# Permission to write to log

Tags: permissions, logs

I'm working on a Python + Django application and it writes logs.

As I run app locally, logged-in as my user, I would like to enable my user to write logs to `/var/logs`.

I tried to add my user to `syslog` group: `sudo usermod -a -G syslog mauro`, but it does not works.

I wouldn't like to change path permissions (aka `chmod +777 /var/logs`), so, I can use the same set of settings for all environments.

Is there another way to do that, than change path permissions?

Comment: You don't need to give the user write access to `/var/log`. The application itself will write there on its own as long as it's set to do so in the config.

Comment: @NasirRiley but as Iḿ running the app as my user, this is the user that will try write/create files in `var/log/*.log`.

Comment: Then change the config to write the log to another directory that is owned by that user.

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want!!

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Why not? That would be a better and safer solution than giving the user full write access to `/var/log`.

Comment: @Kusalananda As I said, I would like to have a base set of settings (ex: `log: /valr/logs/application.log`) for any environment (dev/prod/sandbox). And then, I would have specific settings for environment, like database.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762675/537980

Comment: @NasirRiley the app can only do what the user can do, but `syslogd` can do it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I understand that which is why I suggested that he change the config of the app to write to another directory. He can use `syslogd` as you've suggested.

Comment: @NasirRiley `systemd` is a service (not a directory). It can do logging to `/var/log`. So gives you permission to log to `/var/log`, but you can not do anything else with `/var/log`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I know. I'm not suggesting that he write to `systemd` or `syslogd` (as such a thing would be impossible).

Comment: There's a possible mix-up here between `/var/logs` (a less common name) and `/var/log` (the more common name). If you've created your own `/var/logs` directory, is syslog the group-owner of it and does it have group-write permissions? Did you restart your app *after* adding your user to the syslog group?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming Unix/Linux environment and it is supporting acl implementation, you can apply an acl like this:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:mauro:rw /var/logs
```

> This  utility (setfacl) sets  Access  Control  Lists (ACLs) of files and directories, i.e. sets what permission a user(s)/group(s) can have on a particular file or directory.
>
> Refer to man-page of setfacl(1)

Also, `setfacl` has a recursive option (-R) just like `chmod`:

You can use capital-x `X` permission, which means:

```
execute only if the file is a directory or already has
execute permission for some user (X)
```

So the new command will be like:

```
setfacl -R -m u:mauro:rwX /var/logs
```

Comment: the answer before edition does not worked. But, with recursive option works!!

Comment: that's great..it serves the purpose.

Comment: @erTugRul Could you write something about _what this does_ and what the given user is allowed to do after executing this command?  Are they, for example, able to create and delete files in the directory? Could they accidentally overwrite other log files?

Comment: This would effectively give the user write access to the entire `/var/log` directory.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, it will, but to /var/logs not to /var/log, check the question.

Comment: @erTugRul _I_ know what the command does. A reader of the answer might not know what the command does. The description should be part of the answer, with any caveats.

Comment: This answers the more general question about file permissions. But the OP asked about logging, there is a much better answer involving `syslogd`. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762675/537980

Comment: @erTugRul `/var/logs` is apparently a typo in the question. It's clear that he's talking about `/var/log` or else he wouldn't have been so worried about changing the permissions to it.

Comment: @Nasir, you are right that it might be a typo. But the answer serves the purpose of what OP asked. In question he was worried about to give 777 permission to /var/log, not about giving the ownership to another single user also.

Comment: @Kusalananda added some details about command.

Comment: No system I checked for it had `setfacl`.

Answer (score 4):

Create the log file as root,

```
sudo touch /var/log/mylogfile.log
```

Make it owned by the correct user:

```
sudo chown user:group /var/log/mylogfile.log
```

If you do logfile rotations, make sure that the rotation service (`logrotate` or whatever you are using) creates or leaves an empty file with the right ownership whenever the logfile is rotated.

To allow a single user to write multiple logfiles, create a directory `/var/log/mylogs` that is owned by the user in question, then create the logfiles in that directory.

Comment: @Kuslananda this works fine for one file. Is there some solution for user level? As I work with other apps, I would like to enable my user, as a "log writer".

Comment: "If you do logfile rotations, make sure that the rotation service (logrotate or whatever you are using) creates or leaves an empty file with the right ownership whenever the logfile is rotated." Can you elaborate on the correct way to do this?

Comment: @FaheemMitha If you rotate the logs as root (as is commonly done), there is no issue with removing or renaming the current log file. However, the service that logs to the file may not have the permissions necessary to create the file in order to write to it, in the case when the service logs _directly_ to the file. If the service uses a syslog facility to do logging, then this should not be an issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda Debian uses `logrotate`. In my case I created a subdirectory for the getmail logs, because that's what exim does.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, creating a subdirectory with the correct permissions and writing the logs there would solve the issue too.

Answer (score 2):

`syslogd` is your friend here. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762675/537980

`syslogd` has permission to write to this directory. It is designed for logging. It will not give any other permissions (just logging). See the linked above for more info (I am not an expert. I only know that it exists, and is what you need).

Comment: this is another very nice approach, but it implies in to change log handler. If it is doable, this answer could be satisfactory. And, as the answer you pointed says "If syslogd is running on your box, you can try to use SysLogHandler".